# How can I solve NumberFormatException when string endswith zero in Java?

Tags: java

I have written code to convert string into int but I'm getting error when string ends with zero '0'.

I have tried this,

`int val=Integer.parseInt(s);`

Input string,

`9876543210`

Comment: Post an example of such string.

Comment: Try using longs instead of ints.

Comment: The problem is the number, it's to big to be converted to `int`. Parse it to `long`.

Comment: Yes, This is working thanks !

Comment: I used this,  ```long val=Long.parseLong(s);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be trying to parse a string which does not contain a parsable integer.
as document [Integer.parseInt(String str)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) says.

> Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value. The resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the parseInt(java.lang.String, int) method.
>
> Throws:
>       NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

With some example we can understand it.

```java
String s = "3t0";
int val=Integer.parseInt(s);
// Will throw exception 

String s = "9876543210"; 
int val=Integer.parseInt(s);
// Will throw an Exception because  9876543210 is not an Integer see the Integer range of values (-2^31 to 2^31-1) 


String s = "433"
int val=Integer.parseInt(s);
// Will successfully parse
```